# Chrome PWA "Create shortcut" for my second account's Google Calendar

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to make a PWA shortcut for my second logged-in account's Google Calendar (url is https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/1/r). However, whenever I make a shortcut via Menu => More Tools => Create shortcut, it reads calendar.google.com's manifest and sets the start url to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r, which is my primary account.

How can I force Chrome to use the URL for my second account? I don't want to create a new Chrome profile and do it that way; I'd like it the shortcut to always open the second account in my main Chrome profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem by changing the manifest reference.

Here's an example of how to do it for Google Keep:

1. Open your second account in Google Keep and in Developer Tools find the reference to the web manifest.

[image]

2. Open the manifest in a new tab and rehost it on a JSONbin-like hosting website, modifying whatever you deem necessary. I used npoint.io, here's what mine looks like.

[image]

3. Take the direct URL to the JSON payload and replace it in Dev Tools in the Google Keep page.

[image]

4. Now you can go to Menu -> More Tools -> Create Shortcut, and your new shortcut will start at the start URL you supplied in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Need a similar setup where i need to use second PWA for a different microsoft teams account. Need to use second google chrome user profile to access the other teams account.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).